# FOSFacebookBundle facebook_login_button({'autologoutlink': true}) doesn't show "Logout" after success login

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've implemented FOSUserBundle+FOSFacebookBundle and I can successfully register and login as both regular and facebook user.

After logging in as a facebook user these sessions are created:

1. fbm_XXXXXX
2. fbsr_XXXXXX

Template contains this code:

```
{{ facebook_initialize({'xfbml': true, 'fbAsyncInit': 'onFbInit();'}) }}
{{ facebook_login_button({'autologoutlink': true}) }}
<script>
function goLogIn(){
    window.location = "{{ path('fos_facebook_security_check') }}";
}
function onFbInit() {
    if (typeof(FB) != 'undefined' && FB != null ) {
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
            if (response.session || response.authResponse) {
                setTimeout(goLogIn, 5000);
            } else {
                window.location = "{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}";
            }
        });
    }
}                      
</script>
```

When I click FB-login button pop-up apears, I fulfill the form, FB-login button in my templates changes to "logout", I wait 5 secs till redirect.
After redirection I'm properly logged in but the button changes to "login" (instead of "logout") again and I cannot force proper facebook logout.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

**SOLVED**
There should be `'status': true` in `facebook_initialize` arguments.

**CONFIGURATION**
security.yml

```
services:
    my.facebook.user:
        class: Strict\UserBundle\Security\User\Provider\FacebookProvider
        arguments:
            facebook: "@fos_facebook.api"
            userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
            validator: "@validator"
            container: "@service_container"
    strict_user.my_provider:
        class: Strict\UserBundle\Security\User\Provider\StrictProvider
        public: false
        arguments: ["@fos_user.user_manager"]      
security:
    factories:
          - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle/Resources/config/security_factories.xml"

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            providers: [fos_userbundle, my_fos_facebook_provider]
        fos_userbundle:
            id: strict_user.my_provider
        my_fos_facebook_provider:
            id: my.facebook.user

    encoders:
        "FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface": sha512

    firewalls:
        public:
            pattern:   ^/
            fos_facebook:
                app_url: "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id="
                server_url: "http://localhost/web/app_dev.php"
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_facebook_security_check
                default_target_path: homepage
                provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                provider: fos_userbundle
            anonymous: true           
            logout:
                path: fos_user_security_logout    
                target: homepage
```

For the rest of the files check documentation of both User and Facebook bundles.

Comment: > I've implemented FOSUserBundle+FOSFacebookBundle and I can
> successfully register and login as both regular and facebook user. Please, take here you configure this bundle

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'll be interested to read about it if so...

Comment: Yes I did. Read me edited post: "SOLVED There should be 'status': true in facebook_initialize arguments."

Comment: You should make your solution an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be `'status': true` in `facebook_initialize` arguments.

`{{ facebook_initialize({'xfbml': true, 'fbAsyncInit': 'onFbInit();', 'status': true }) }}`

**CONFIGURATION**
security.yml

```
services:
    my.facebook.user:
        class: Strict\UserBundle\Security\User\Provider\FacebookProvider
        arguments:
            facebook: "@fos_facebook.api"
            userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
            validator: "@validator"
            container: "@service_container"
    strict_user.my_provider:
        class: Strict\UserBundle\Security\User\Provider\StrictProvider
        public: false
        arguments: ["@fos_user.user_manager"]      
security:
    factories:
          - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle/Resources/config/security_factories.xml"

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            providers: [fos_userbundle, my_fos_facebook_provider]
        fos_userbundle:
            id: strict_user.my_provider
        my_fos_facebook_provider:
            id: my.facebook.user

    encoders:
        "FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface": sha512

    firewalls:
        public:
            pattern:   ^/
            fos_facebook:
                app_url: "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id="
                server_url: "http://localhost/web/app_dev.php"
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_facebook_security_check
                default_target_path: homepage
                provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                provider: fos_userbundle
            anonymous: true           
            logout:
                path: fos_user_security_logout    
                target: homepage
```

For the rest of the files check documentation of both User and Facebook bundles.